# Route [customer.password.request] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

I am trying to get my development box to work so I can work on a development at home as not to alter and mess up the main site. 
I get an error on the development box but not on the main site.

I have set everything up then copied the site via another tutorial. I was able to get all the requirements working and the site works except when I attempt to go to the log in page. I have searched the web for the method used for the route and I cannot find a good explanation of how it works so I can troubleshoot the problem.

```php
div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-2">
                                @if(Session::has('errors'))
                                <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                                    @php ($errors = Session::get('errors'))
                                    @php ($err = $errors->toArray())

                                    {{$err['email'][0]}}
                                </div>
                                @endif
                                <form role="form" id="cust-login-frm" method="POST" action="{{ route('xxx') }}" >
                                  {{csrf_field()}}
                                  <input name="user_type" type="hidden" value="{{ Crypt::encrypt('XX') }}">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{{(Session::has('failed')) ? Session::get('failed') : ''}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>

                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12 submitbtn">
                                        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact"> -->
                                        <button id="cust-login-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Sign In</button>
                                    </div>
                                <center><div> Not Registrated? <a href="{{ route('xxx-customer-registration') }}">Register </a> | <a href="{{ route('customer.password.request') }}">Forgot Password?</a> </div></center>
```

The issue I am having is the hyperlink towards the bottom "{{route('customer.password.request') }}" The route before it I can find and follow but this one with the dot notation I cannot. I cannot provide too many details as this is a live site. I suspect this broke due to my command composer update. The main site was not coded by me and has tons of issues. But it will work and its the same. This one is difficult as the main laravel.org does not have much on the subject. If a guru here can point me to a tutorial or page that will help me understand why I am getting the error "Route [customer.password.request] not defined. (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/customer/auth/xxx.blade.php)". Thanks community. :)
NOTE: I have removed some parts to hide real filenames with xxx.

Comment: Have you defined the `customer.password.request` [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)?

Comment: In web.php have route customer.password.reset ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is track down how this route works. in the web.php it does not exist. I wanted to use what already exists. However running updates broke something. there was a change that caused this to not function. I need to back trace it. I just do not know how these kind of routes work.

Comment: Ok this is going to sound strange. I found the issue. UGH Leave it up to morons to add functions in the files that get changed when things are updated. :/ I found the changes in an older file and added them. The page now works.

Comment: Ok here is one of the things I am going to try. I am going to move those routes out of the vender/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing.php file and into the web.php file where they belong. Hope it doesn't break anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer to my question here is this.
I found out that the routes were placed in the wrong location. 
The morons who did this put the routes in the vender folder file. This was changed when I did an update. So I decided to move them to the web.php and it worked. 
So this issue can be closed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define the route name in web.php

```
Route::any('urlname','controllername@functionname')->name('customer.password.request');
```